# Apache hangs with mod_wsgi + django

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi

I have had Apache + mod_wsgi + django running. For some reason, something has changed on the server and now apache completely hangs--it stops responding to all other requests and has to be stopped and started--when I post a request. Eventually we see a "Premature end of script headers: django.wsgi" error.

We did a strace and one thing I saw that seemed suspicious was "GATEWAY_INTERFACE\0CGI/1.1\0SERVER_PROTOCOL..." (We also see a shutdown being issued.)

Is "GATEWAY_INTERFACE\0CGI/1.1" specifying that it is set up for CGI rather then WSGI? (I have read that premature end of script can results if it is set as CGI.)

Our virtualhost specifies:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess [host] threads=25
WSGIProcessGroup [host]
WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/apache/django.wsgi
```

and I see nothing to do with CGI in the httpd.conf just loading the WSGI module.

Comment: fixed. Problem seemed to be that it was hanging on an import statement in django. When I set WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL} problem was resolved.

Comment: Likely due to third party Python package with C extension module which will not work in sub interpreter. http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ApplicationIssues#Python_Simplified_GIL_State_API

Answer (score 1):

Here, try this one:

http://www.foxhop.net/django-virtualenv-apache-mod_wsgi

Remember to add python and project paths to syspath.